# Unable to access flutter UI elements in widget test

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, widget, bloc

I am trying to write a widget test for my flutter screens which are built with bloc. But I am not able to access any of my widget through the test. Following is my widget test code:

```
    FeedbackListBloc feedbackListBloc;
  FeedbackListRepository feedbackListRepository;
  PrefStore prefStore;

  group('login error handling', () {
    feedbackListRepository = MockFeedbackListRepository();
    prefStore = MockPrefStore();
    feedbackListBloc = FeedbackListBloc(feedbackListRepository,prefStore);

    testWidgets('validate Feedback List widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      Widget testWidget = new MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQueryData(),
          child: MaterialApp(home: FeedbackList(feedbackListBloc: feedbackListBloc))
      );
      Widget localizedWidget = Localizations(
        delegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        locale: Locale('en'),
        child: testWidget,
      );
      await tester.pumpWidget(localizedWidget);
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byIcon(Icons.add), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
```

I am always getting following error in my expect method:

```
test/widget_test/dashboard/feedback/feedback_list/ui/feedback_list_test.dart
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "CircularProgressIndicator" (ignoring offstage
widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#4      main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///Users/pankajsahdevea/Desktop/HD/Work/Haufe/Code/IF2.0/if_ui_Sep13,2019/test/widget_test/dashboard/feedback/feedback_list/ui/feedback_list_test.dart:45:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      testWidgets.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:124:25)
#6      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:696:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:679:14)
#10     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1050:24)
#16     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:1047:15)
#17     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:121:22)
#18     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:171:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:242:15)
#24     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:239:5)
#25     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:169:33)
#30     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:13)
#31     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:392:25)
#45     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
#46     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
#47     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
(elided 28 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, package dart:async-patch, and package stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:
  file:///Users/pankajsahdevea/Desktop/HD/Work/Haufe/Code/IF2.0/if_ui_Sep13,2019/test/widget_test/dashboard/feedback/feedback_list/ui/feedback_list_test.dart line 45
The test description was:
  validate Feedback List widget
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Test failed. See exception logs above.
The test description was: validate Feedback List widget
```